# how can I create a property to Android?

Tags: android

I would like to create a persist property to Android

It is a persisit property.

I have read the doc through
https://source.android.com/docs/core/architecture/configuration/add-system-properties

But the question is I cannot see my newly created property.

My question is,

1. What modules I should build?
2. What files(library) I should push into device?

PS: I pushed build.prop.

Thanks